# Is "constiption" a recognized legal concept?

Tags: any-jurisdiction

Quite a few questions have been asked about "constiption" on Law SE and other SE sites. Is "constiption" a real legal concept?

Answer (score 3):

### No

[This term appears to have originated from an anonymous user of this site.](https://law.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1549/44937)

Constiption is not a recognized legal concept, nor is it an English word in any other context. All [DuckDuckGo](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=%22constiption%22) hits are either SE questions or misspellings of "constipation".